# Fields of injected bean are null when trying to set them via JSF

Tags: jsf, cdi

I am following a book about JEE and trying to implement a simple JSF example. I want to register and persist a *Customer* via a JSF page and a controller.

The problem is that the attributes ot the injected *Customer* in the controller are always null, no matter what I type into the JSF registration form.

The registerController.persist() method is getting executed on form submission, though.

When I submit the form with the email "user@email.com" for example, I would expect the injected Customer in the controller to have an email, but it is always null. Perhaps somebody can give me a suggestion where the problem lies.

The JSF page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>
        <h:outputText value="Onlineshop"/>
    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Registrieren"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputLabel value="E-Mail:"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{registerController.customer.email}"></h:inputText>
            <h:outputLabel value="Kennwort:"/>
            <h:inputSecret value="#{registerController.customer.password}"></h:inputSecret>
            <h:commandButton action="#{registerController.persist}" value="Registrieren"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The Controller:

```
package de.java2enterprise.onlineshop;

import de.java2enterprise.onlineshop.model.Customer;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RegisterController {

    @PersistenceUnit()
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction ut;

    @Inject
    private Customer customer;

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public String persist() {
        try {
            ut.begin();
            emf.createEntityManager().persist(customer);
            ut.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "/register.xhtml";
    }
}
```

And the Customer:

```
package de.java2enterprise.onlineshop.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * 
 * @author Alexander Salvanos
 *
 * The persistent class for the CUSTOMER database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(schema="ONLINESHOP", name="CUSTOMER")
@NamedQuery(
        name="Customer.findAll", 
        query="SELECT c FROM Customer c")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name="CUSTOMER_ID_GENERATOR", 
            sequenceName="SEQ_CUSTOMER",
            schema="ONLINESHOP",
            allocationSize=1,
            initialValue=1)
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
            generator="CUSTOMER_ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Item
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="seller")
    private Set<Item> offers;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Item
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="buyer")
    private Set<Item> purchases;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<Item> getOffers() {
        return this.offers;
    }

    public void setOffers(Set<Item> offers) {
        this.offers = offers;
    }

    public Item addOffer(Item offer) {
        Set<Item> offers = getOffers();
        if(offers == null) {
            offers = new HashSet<Item>();
        }
        offers.add(offer);
        offer.setSeller(this);

        return offer;
    }

    public Item removeOffer(Item offer) {
        getOffers().remove(offer);
        offer.setSeller(null);

        return offer;
    }

    public Set<Item> getPurchases() {
        return this.purchases;
    }

    public void setPurchases(Set<Item> purchases) {
        this.purchases = purchases;
    }

    public Item addPurchase(Item purchase) {
        Set<Item> purchases = getPurchases();
        if(purchases == null) {
            purchases = new HashSet<Item>();
        }
        purchases.add(purchase);
        purchase.setBuyer(this);
        return purchase;
    }   

    public Item removePurchase(Item purchase) {
        getPurchases().remove(purchase);
        purchase.setBuyer(null);

        return purchase;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Customer)) {
            return false;
        }
        Customer other = (Customer) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return id + "-" + email + "-" + password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your injected entity has a value? Or is it `null`?

Comment: It has value, but all it's fields are null.

Comment: Use `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped` package instead of `javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped`. May be not the problem but you must not mix JSF and CDI annotations.

Comment: Thank you @Rouliboy that was it, it is finally working now. Perhaps you can post an answer here so I can mark it as best answer.

Comment: Great! I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `JSF` and `CDI` annotations, using `javax.inject.Named` (CDI) and `javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped` (JSF).

Use **`javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`** instead.